# Is there any chance that when our .then callbacks are being pushed onto the microtask queue, another random function is placed somewhere in middle?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, scheduled-tasks, event-loop

I was watching a video on Promise at CodeSmith YouTube channel when the instructor said, .then takes the callback function and pushes that cb function into the hidden onFulfillment array which are later triggered once the Promise is resolved with the first argument being the value its resolved with!

Now I think the detail is a bit incomplete because I later found out not only does .then pushes the cb function into the hidden onFulfilment array for later execution but it also immediately returns a pending promise and then when that cb function runs and whatever value is returned, thats the value thats resolved with that pending promise thats returned by .then!

What I also noticed if the promise is immediately resolved, then the cb function will be directly put into the micro task queue!

Now my question is, lets say I have this code:

```
let p = new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000, 'someValue'))

p.then() x 1000 times
```

Yes, what if we have 1000 .thens?

Now I do realise all 1000 functions will be pushed into the hidden onFulfillment array synchronously and will only execute once the Promise is resolved but thats where I'm a bit confused!

As soon as a promise is resolved, its supposed to take one function from the array and put into the microtask queue, it'll do this for however many functions we pass (I have only seen people doing one .then)

... but In our case, its 1000, so how is this gonna work ?

Is there any possibility that only 20 functions are put onto the microtask queue and then some completely random function is pushed in the middle?

What if my P2 has resolved so its functions are also gonna be put into the microtask queue so could there be a clash? like 20 from p is pushed onto the microtask queue and then 5 from p2 and vice versa?

**I know, practically I wont be doing this EVER, but I am asking this out of curiosity, I checked Google and dint find anything that answers this so any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: Are you asking whether the callbacks will receive the correct argument? Yes, surely no other function can accidentally push some wrong argument for the wrong function into the queue. Or are you asking about the guaranteed execution order?

Comment: @deceze - Sorry English is not my native! What I'm saying is .then will put the callback function into the root Promise object's hidden onFulfillment array for later execution, once our promise is resolved! but what if we go completely insane and push 1000 callbacks? Will the 1000 functions go into the job queue one by one? Wont there be any case that some other Promise's .then function is pushed into the job queue? Like we have 1000 functions in our hidden array so putting all of them should take time! Hope you got my point

Answer (score 1):

> As soon as a promise is resolved, its supposed to take one function from the array and put into the microtask queue, it'll do this for however many functions we pass.

Yes, it just puts them into the queue all at once. Even if its 1000s of jobs.

> Is there any possibility that only 20 functions are put onto the microtask queue and then some completely random function is pushed in the middle?

No.

However, you should not rely on this behaviour - if you care about the timing between two handlers of your promise, either chain them one after the other, or put both codes into the same handler.

Comment: "Yes, it just puts them into the queue all at once. Even if its 1000s of jobs."

Thats what was confusing me, thanks for the clarity! :)

Comment: That's what the queue is good for after all :-)

Comment: Complete nit-picking: it is theoretically possible to have a microtask enter the "spin the event loop" algorithm, in which case different tasks/microtasks could get executed before its end. However I never saw this case with my eyes, I think `showModalDialog()` was triggering something like that, but given it's been removed...

Comment: @Kaiido Ah, you might be onto something there… but will those tasks get their own microtask queue, or will they first execute the tasks that are currently queued?

Comment: That's exactly something I would have loved to test, but once again, I couldn't  make this happen... Firefox uses a kind of "spin the event loop" with `alert()`, but it's explicitly modified to not execute microtasks... The HTML parser also calls it quite a few times, but we can't call it from scripts so still not observable... So I believe it's only "theoretically" possible, but in the facts I don't think it can happen currently.